# Allow invalid date in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-mode

I have below query which is working if i run it directly on PHPMyadmin but not when i run it using laravel.

```
select SUM(p.quantity_held * s.current_share_price) as mv 
from portfolio_holding p, portfolios po, securities s 
where `p`.`security_id` = s.security_id and `po`.`portfolio_id` = p.portfolio_id 
      and `po`.`status_id` in (1, 2) 
      and (`p`.`sell_date` is null or `p`.`sell_date` = '0000-00-00' or `p`.`sell_date` > now()) 
      and s.security_id <> 0 
limit 1
```

It throws below error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1525 Incorrect DATE value: ''0000-00-00'

I have set mysql_mode to ALLOW_INVALID_DATES in database.

Also used below one when before executing my query in laravel:

> DB::statement("set session sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'");

Also strict mode is set to false in laravel conig/database.php, but still above query throws error.

Comment: NO_ZERO_DATE and NO_ZERO_IN_DATE SQL modes must be not set. Strict mode must be disabled too. PS. But I'd recommend to replace invalid dates values with NULLs.

Comment: `DB::statement("set session sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES'");` This cannot help - zero is not valid month or day value. Read this mode description carefully.

Comment: i only have ALLOW_INVALID_DATES sqm_mode in database other then that doesn't have naything on database.

Comment: I'll repeat - ALLOW_INVALID_DATES claims `'0000-00-00'` value **incorrect**!!! One more time - read this mode description **CAREFULLY**!!!

Comment: aah okay then which mode i should use to solve this one.

Comment: the issue is its working with PHPMyadmin but not with laravel. So what changes i should do other then setting dates with NULL value.

Comment: Check sf strict mode is enabled in `config/database.php` in the configuration you're using.  Disable it.

Comment: @IGP it is already set as false